# Eliminating Previous Scene After New Scene Is Shown

Tags: java, javafx

I am just beginning to learn JAVAFX and I have run into a problem now. I have a login screen and after I clicked login, a dialog box appeared and the problem is I don't know how to eliminate the login screen after the dialog has showed up. Please help me. This is my code

Main.java (contains login screen)

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../view/LoginScreen.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Weltes Mart O2 Tank Module");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

LoginController.java (showing a dialog box)

```
public class LoginController {

    @FXML private Text loginStatusMessage;
    @FXML private Button btnLogin;

    @FXML public void handleLoginButton(ActionEvent event){
        System.out.println("BUTTON PRESSED");

        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../view/LoginSuccessDialog.fxml"));
            Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any [`Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) in a `Scene` to get a reference to that scene. You can use a `Scene` to get the `Window` that contains it. You can close that window.

Assuming the `Node` fields are actually injected by the loader, you can close the `Stage` using this code:

```
btnLogin.getScene().getWindow().hide();
```

Comment: Just a note here: Either make sure to do this *after* you show the new window, or call [`Platform.setImplicitExit(false);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#setImplicitExit-boolean-) somewhere in your application first.